# Java - Properly format a String given escape sequences and escape characters

Tags: java, string, escaping

Given new line (\n), tab (\t) and an escape character \ how can I given a string format it properly so it deals with these escape sequences and escape characters properly. Example 1:

```
"string \\t \t"
```

The output would be:

```
"string \t    "
```

So in this case \\t is escaped to just \t and \t is formatted with a tab

Example 2:

```
"string \\t \n \\n"
```

The output is:

```
"string \t
\n"
```

I tried brute-forcing a solution but it didn't work as I am having problems delimiting tabs and spaces with a backslash infront.

```
String v= "..." //v for value
v = v.replace("\\\"","\"");
v = v.replace("\\\\","\\");
v = v.replace("\\t", "  ");
v = v.replace("\\n", "\n");
v = v.replace("\\\t", "\\t");
v = v.replace("\\\n", "\\n");
```

If I ran that code through the first example it would give:

```
"string         "
```

Comment: ``\\`` is escape for a backslash. ``\n`` is escape for newline. ``\t`` is escape for a tab character. ``\\"`` is escape for a quote. It's really that simple. You say you *"tried brute-forcing a solution"*, but you didn't say *what* you were trying to solve, so how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want `\\t` to be evaluated as `\[tab]` rather than `\t`?

Comment: @Andreas \\ should escape a backslash and \\t or \\n should escape a tab or new line yes

Comment: @Zircon I want \\t to be a literal \t

Comment: So you want a string that contains a ``\`` immediately followed by a `t`, to be updated to replace the two-character substring ``\t`` with a single *tab* character? If so, update your question and clearly say that.

Comment: Perhaps you can use [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String input)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

Answer (score 1):

looks like the one "brute force" combination you didn't try is correct

```
replace("\\t", "\t")
```

reading "replace all < backslash >< t > combinations with < tab >"

String them all together to get

```
v = v.replace("\\t", "\t").replace("\\n", "\n")
```

(there's no need to replace \ by itself)

Answer (score 1):

You can first is replace escaped symbols and then replace escaped slashes with single slashes:

```
[\, \, \, n] -> [\, \, \n] -> [\, \n]
```

We can do this by finding occurrences of two slash pairs:

```
(^|[^\\])(\\\\)*

- (^|[^\\]) is the start of the string or not a slash
- (\\\\)* is slash pairs
```

Combine this with the symbol you want to replace (for example `\n`):

```
((^|[^\\])(\\\\)*)(\\n)
```

Then we escape this string for java:

```
((^|[^\\\\])(\\\\\\\\)*)(\\\\n)
```

Now you can write a helper method for this regex which keeps the first group `$1` and replaces the second group:

```
public static String replaceEscapedChar(
    final String source, 
    final char escaped, 
    final char actual
) {
    final String replacee = "(\\\\" + escaped + ")";
    final String replacement = "$1" + actual;
    return source.replaceAll("((^|[^\\\\])(\\\\\\\\)*)" + replacee, replacement); 
}
```

For example. The following produces:

```
replaceEscapedChar("Test\\\\\\nTest\\\\n", 'n', '\n');

Test\\
Test\\n
```

---

PS: You can also remove the quotes afterwards by writing:

```
source.replaceAll("((\\\\\\\\)+)", "\\\\");
```